# Trying to fire jquery validate on form submit using .submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

But it isn't firing when I hit submit. It submits but doesn't do anything. Any ideas? The alert doesn't even get called :(

The page I'm doing this on, is my Checkout page on:

http://rsatestamls.kaliocommerce.com

(Need a product in your cart to proceed to checkout)

My Javascript code is:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Method input:checkbox").change(function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            var checkname = $(this).attr("name");
            $('input[type=checkbox][id=OnAccount]').prop('value', 'True')
            $("input:checkbox[name='" + checkname + "']").not(this).removeAttr("checked");
        } else {
            $('input[type=checkbox][id=OnAccount]').val('No');
        }
    });
    $("#CheckoutOptions input:checkbox").change(function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            var checkname = $(this).attr("name");
            $("input:checkbox[name='" + checkname + "']").not(this).removeAttr("checked");
        }
    });
});

$("#CheckOut").submit(function (event) {
    alert("Handler for .submit() called.");
    jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
        debug: false,
        success: "valid"
    });
    $("#CheckOut").validate({
        rules: {
            FirstName: {
                required: true
            },
            LastName: {
                required: true
            },
            Email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            Phone: {
                required: true,
                digits: true
            },
            Address1: {
                required: true
            },
            City: {
                required: true
            },
            PostalCode: {
                required: true,
                digits: true
            },
            Country: {
                required: true
            },
            State: {
                required: true
            },
            pwd: {
                required: true
            },
            pwd_confirm: {
                required: true
            },
            FName_SHIP: {
                required: true
            },
            LName_Ship: {
                required: true
            },
            Phone_Ship: {
                required: true,
                digits: true
            },
            Address1_Ship: {
                required: true
            },
            City_Ship: {
                required: true
            },
            PostalCode_SHIP: {
                required: true,
                digits: true
            },
            COUNTRY_SHIP: {
                required: true
            },
            State_SHIP: {
                required: true
            },
            NameOnCard: {
                required: {
                    depends: function (element) {
                        return $("#CCMethod").is(":checked");
                    }
                }
            },
            CreditCardType: {
                required: {
                    depends: function (element) {
                        return $("#CCMethod").is(":checked");
                    }
                }
            },
            CardNumber: {
                required: {
                    depends: function (element) {
                        return $("#CCMethod").is(":checked");
                    }
                }
            },
            CardExpMonth: {
                required: {
                    depends: function (element) {
                        return $("#CCMethod").is(":checked");
                    }
                }
            },
            CardExpYear: {
                required: {
                    depends: function (element) {
                        return $("#CCMethod").is(":checked");
                    }
                }
            },
            CVC: {
                required: {
                    depends: function (element) {
                        return $("#CCMethod").is(":checked");
                    }
                }
            },
            customernumber: {
                required: {
                    depends: function (element) {
                        return $("#OnAccount").is(":checked");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
populateCartTotal();

</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `submit` handler isn't in your `$(document).ready` block, but should be.  The handler is never getting attached.

In fact, you shouldn't use a `submit` handler at all, here.  Just put your validate call in the `ready` block.  See the demo here: http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Method input:checkbox").change(function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            var checkname = $(this).attr("name");
            $('input[type=checkbox][id=OnAccount]').prop('value', 'True')
            $("input:checkbox[name='" + checkname + "']").not(this).removeAttr("checked");
        } else {
            $('input[type=checkbox][id=OnAccount]').val('No');
        }
    });
    $("#CheckoutOptions input:checkbox").change(function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            var checkname = $(this).attr("name");
            $("input:checkbox[name='" + checkname + "']").not(this).removeAttr("checked");
        }
    });

    // move this stuff to here
    jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
        debug: false,
        success: "valid"
    });
    $("#CheckOut").validate({
        rules: {
            // all those rules here
        }
    });
});
```

populateCartTotal();

Comment: Bam! That worked! Thank you! I thought that I couldn't, for some reason, use .submit inside of .ready

Comment: Glad it helped! You may want to simplify it, though, by naming a function and simply using the function name in the `submit` call, rather than calling it as an anonymous function.  But you can definitely call it as you have it.

Comment: Actually, my bad - got excited when I saw the alert - it only fired the alert, but not the actual validation, and the form submitted anyways. What the ._.

Answer (score 1):

As an addendum to Ed's answer, I would also recommend setting up your validation scheme **outside** of the submit() handler.

Comment: Out of curiosity, could you elaborate a bit on what you mean? Kinda lost me there in all honesty.

Comment: You placed `$("#CheckOut").validate()` inside of the handler for `$("#CheckOut").submit()`. It's better practice to move it out of there so that its immediate "parent" is `$(document).ready(function () { ... })`.